# How to disable scrolling when responsive menu overlay is active

Tags: menu, responsive, fullscreen

I am using an example from w3schools and can`t figure out how to disable the scrolling when the menu is opened. Any solution (java, css, etc) will be most appreciated.

Source:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_overlay_no-anim

Codepen: https://cutt.ly/6BDIKIQ

Comment: So far I tried   document.getElementById("myNav").style.overflow = 'hidden'; and height vh but cant get the desired effect

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your codepen https://codepen.io/tomcatbuzz/pen/wvEwRrM
I had this issue before and add a class called body.hide with overflow:hidden to your css and call with classList.add in the open function, classList.remove in the close function.

style.css

```
body.hide { overflow: hidden; }
```

index.js

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "block";
  document.body.classList.add('hide')
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "none";
  document.body.classList.remove('hide')
}
```

The overflow hidden removes the scroll bar and keeps any content from scrolling in the overlay menu. Hope this might help others if they need it.